# Accessing mysql_query results

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following columns in a table of mine ;

**id /
owner /
del /
eq /
type**

IF there are 2x of the same ID and 2x of the same type in one row. You cannot add a 3rd. I can do this with a PHP If statement. But I have tried to count using this ;

```
$tot = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item WHERE id='$id'AND type='1'");
$tot1 = mysql_fetch_array($tot);
```

Here it should count the rows where the ID  ( that matches the person logged in ) and how many of them are also type 1. But when I echo this I just get the word "Array"

Answer (score 1):

The result of `mysql_fetch_array` is an array that maps columns to their values in the current row, both assosciatively and by index. So, in this case, you can get the result of `count(*)` by referring to `$tot1[0]`.

Comment: Hello. Is it best to be using this how I am now, or is there a more efficient way to do this? All I need is a variable that counts the amount of type 1. But I am wondering if this way is not efficient maybe?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of echoing, use var_dump() or print_r()